# External Table is not in correct format while reading Excel file

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am trying to read a very simple excel file. I keep getting the error saying "External table is not in the expected format."

below is my code:

```
Public Sub ImportToDataTable(ByVal FilePath As String, ByVal Extension As String, ByVal isHDR As String)
    Dim conStr As String = ""
    Select Case Extension
        Case ".xlsx"
            conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Excel07ConString").ConnectionString()
            Exit Select

    End Select

    conStr = String.Format(conStr, FilePath, isHDR)

    Dim connExcel As New OleDbConnection(conStr)

    Dim cmdExcel As New OleDbCommand()

    Dim oda As New OleDbDataAdapter()

    Dim dt As New DataTable()
    cmdExcel.Connection = connExcel
    'Get the name of First Sheet 

    connExcel.Open()
```

I get this error at ConnExcel.open()

My FilePath is C:\Book1.xlsx. My connection string is:

```
<configuration>
```

```
<add name ="Excel07ConString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0}; Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR={1}'"/>
```

I have Header in the file. Below is my Excel file.

![Col1  Col2    Col3    Col4
1   2   3   4
5   6   78  89
12  23  45  56
]

I am not sure what am I doing wrong. I googled this problem and it seems there is something wrong with my connection string, but I am not sure what is wrong with my connection string. I am using Office 2010 and visual studio 2010.

Below is the connection string that is generated:

```
"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\ExcelFiles\Book2.xlsx; Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES'"
```

any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Show the connectionstring that is generated.

Comment: "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\ExcelFiles\Book2.xlsx; Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES'"

Comment: The only thing I can see is that you have a single quote (') around the extended headers. All the examples I can see have a double quote character ("). Might be worth trying that. Also, check that each column does have a header in the first row - your example data is not very well formatted.

Comment: I saved the same file as .xls and it worked fine with the same connection string, but if it has a extension of xlsx then it doesn't work properly.

Comment: Hmm. Don't know. Could it be anything to do with the Xml in the Extended Properties? I've had success with ACE before and don't recall using that.

Comment: Try this Extended Properties="Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1"; for the Exnetded Properties - add IMEX=1. Might not make any difference though

Comment: should I add it at the end of the string

Comment: Might as well (I don't think it matters but that's where it's usually put).

Comment: I added this in the connection string and got the same error "External table is not in the expected format."